# AWS glue is not able to read Chinese characters in a MySQL database

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, etl, aws-glue

I have data stored in an AWS RDS table `source`. This table contains some Chinese characters.

How can I configure my AWS glue so that it correctly copies the data in the table to another table, `dest`?

I've told JDBC to use UTF-8 encoding.

[image]

If I print the content of the table in my python script, I get the following text:

`\u4e8c\u578b\u7cd6\u5c3f\u75c5`

The original data of the above text are 6 Chinese characters.

But the text doesn't seem to be an UTF-8 encoded string. Because I can't decode them correctly with [this online tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode).

Here's the code I use to print the text:

[image]

After the job of AWS glue completes, the data in the destination table, `dest`, becomes `?????`, which is incorrect.

The following python 2 script can correctly print the Chinese characters in the table.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="remoteHost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="myName",         # your username
                     passwd="myPassword",  # your password
                     db="jonhydb")        # name of the data base

# you must create a Cursor object. It will let
#  you execute all the queries you need
cur = db.cursor()

# Use all the SQL you like
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM source")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]

db.close()
```

Do AWS glue and the above code use different mechanisms to communicate with MySQL database?

Anyone knows how to handle character encoding issue when using AWS glue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Brian, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Any updates on this guys? I am not sure whether there is any solution on this yet.